Can we create SQL Server database project in .NET 8 in Visual Studio 2022?
In our solution, we have database projects in .NET Framework 4.6.2. We wanted to migrate these database projects to .NET 8, but we are not able to see .NET 8 in the "Target Framework" dropdown, even though we have .NET 8 installed (this is visible for other type of projects like, ASP.NET Core MVC app, etc).
We wanted to know if its even possible to migrate existing .NET Framework 4.6.2 SQL Server database project to .NET 8 or not? Can you please suggest?
We tried to create new project after installing .NET 8 but still not able to see it in "Target Framework" dropdown of properties section of SQL Server database project

SQL Server does not (yet) support .Net Core, so you are "stuck" at  .Net Framework releases (< .Net 5).

"database projects" do you mean SQLCLR? Or do you just mean Entity Framework or similar?

Hi @Charlieface, here we are referring project type 'SQL Server Database Project' of visual studio 2022.

Well it's primarily designed for T-SQL coding such as procedures and table/index definitions. But if you intend to use it for SQLCLR: no that only supports .NET Framework 4.x anyway

Why do you want to migrate .NET Framework 4.6.2 SQL Server database project to .NET 8? SQL Server database does not directly support .NET Core or target frameworks of .NET 5 and higher (such as .NET 8).
